# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript

Can you guys here help me solve this problem? I can't navigate to another link via the anchor tag, which only happens on mobile devices and I think this is the fault but I can't fix it. Thank you!
Here is my code

```js
var OnePageNavigation = function() {
    var navToggler = $('.site-menu-toggle');
    $("body").on("click", ".main-menu li a[href^='#'], .smoothscroll[href^='#'], .site-mobile-menu .site-nav-wrap li a", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $(hash).offset().top
      }, 600, 'easeInOutExpo');
  });
  
  $('.gototop').on('click', function() {


      $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $('body').offset().top
      }, 600, 'easeInOutExpo');
  });
  };
  OnePageNavigation();
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `this.hash` to see if it's undefined?

Comment: No,I haven't. I'm not sure about the value of this.hass to log